# What filter was used on this photo?

Tags: effect, apps

[image]

Coul you please help me find out the name of this filter?

Comment: Please see [
Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit your question (and title) correspondingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is an increase in saturation, a raised black point and some film-like grain.

It looks like the colors are slightly flat looking, not very contrast-y. Especially the grass which looks flattened and saturated.

Comment: could please name some filters, tht look like this one?

Comment: I don't know filter names, it's more of an Instagram thing I believe

Comment: @Creepy not everything is a "filter". Post-processing of images is not always a "one-click" effect